# CSS "fill" issue in mozilla

Tags: css

I have an issue on mozilla. 
This is the css code:

```
.accordion__title.collapsed .shape {
    fill: #BF0A30;
}
```

I tried to use

```
webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
```

with no any result.

This is the html code:

```
<a class="accordion__title no-underline collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="uw-invloed/#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">
    Informerende / opiniërende bijeenkomsten
    <svg class="shape shape--plus">
        <use xlink:href="#shape--plus"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

So ideea is the in chrome is working on mozilla not. What should I do ? Thx

Comment: can you make a fiddle? Cause I have no clue in what context you place this all. Having HTML would also be handy

Comment: I cannot do a fiddle, but I uploaded the html code and yeah svg is used

Comment: heh, okay, but since you use the webkit propperty, dont you think you should also use the `moz` propperty for firefox?

Comment: please give me an example. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I need to correct myself above there, first of all. This is a propperty in the css that is only supported by webkit browsers, such as chrome and safari. Mozilla doesn't have included this in their browser. https://css-tricks.com/examples/TextStroke/. Sorry.

Comment: Are u telling me that I cannot do anything to make this work on firefox ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-color as far as I can see, but dont pin me on it yet, no, it's not supported in firefox. I ll dig a bit deeper on it

Comment: PLease check: http://caniuse.com/#search=fill it said that I can use.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/ check this. SVG colloring this way.

Comment: when I type currentColor it simply disappear in firefox firebug. I checked, in all of the browsers work (even IE) except firefox :(